# How to set different size of navigation drawer in different values folder

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation

I want to resize the width of my navigation drawer between `layout-large` and `layout-xlarge`, so I've created different folders:

```
res/values-sw480dp
res/values-sw600dp
```

But it doesn't work, so i tried:

```
res/values-large
res/values-xlarge
```

But it doesn't work either:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="fr.solutis.solutis.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml              // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml        // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml       // layout for extra-large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra-large in landscape orientation

res/values-mdpi/your.xml         // xmlfor medium-density
res/values-hdpi/your.xml         // xml for high-density
res/values-xhdpi/your.xml        // xml for extra-high-density
res/values-xxhdpi/your.xml       // xml for extra-extra-high-density
res/values-sw600dp/your.xml       // 7"
res/values-sw720dp/your.xml       // 10"
```

Comment: The 
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
value don't change between the different layouts he keep the sw720dp value only

Comment: you check that properly, android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width" declare in another folders' xml. check proper name of xml and declare property in all folders. and than put cursor by pressing "ctrl+" over declaration in activity, its shows selected file out of all folders.